# 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to programming. While I was practicing a Sales tutorial using Jupyter Notebook, I ran into an error. I looked online to see why I got the error, but I don't see what I did wrong. If you can help me out, that would be awesome!!

So the error points out at line 10. I wanted to concatenate the data frame that contains months of sales. This is the line where the error occurs. It tells me 'function' object is not subscriptable.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.read_csv('./Sales_Data/Sales_April_2019.csv')

all_months_data = pd.DataFrame()

files = [file for file in os.listdir('./Sales_Data')]

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv('./Sales_Data/' + file)
    all_months_data = pd.concat[(all_months_data, df)]
```

```
TypeError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-c4df32cba8b5> in <module>
     8 for file in files:
     9    df = pd.read_csv('./Sales_Data/' + file)
--->10    all_months_data = pd.concat[(all_months_data, df)]
    11
    12

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: You need to *call* `pd.concat`, with round brackets, not with square brackets, and you pass it a list of dataframes so `pd.concat([all_months_data, df])`

Comment: This question should be closed because it was caused by a typo, as already noted.

Answer (score 0):

It is typically bad practice to create variables/dataframes dynamically. You are much more likely to introduce bugs to your code by doing so.

I would recommend instantiating your variables without the for loop like so,

```py
d1 = pd.read_csv('path1')
d2 = pd.read_csv('path2')
d3 = pd.read_csv('path3')

all_months_data = pd.concat([d1,d2,d3], ignore_index=True)`
```